# PIP install error with git repository packages

Tags: python, django, git, pip

I have a old django project needs to deploy now. I need to install the exact versions used in this project.

In this project's requirements.txt there are some packages which are from GIT repos.

while installing those requirements using

`pip install -r requirements.txt` its throwing following error.

```
  File "/home/nyros/Desktop/new/rmkenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 70, in __init__
    req = pkg_resources.Requirement.parse(req)
  File "/home/nyros/Desktop/new/rmkenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources.py", line 2606, in parse
    reqs = list(parse_requirements(s))
  File "/home/nyros/Desktop/new/rmkenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources.py", line 2544, in parse_requirements
    line, p, specs = scan_list(VERSION,LINE_END,line,p,(1,2),"version spec")
  File "/home/nyros/Desktop/new/rmkenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources.py", line 2512, in scan_list
    raise ValueError("Expected "+item_name+" in",line,"at",line[p:])
ValueError: ('Expected version spec in', 'django_filebrowser-origin/HEAD', 'at', '/HEAD')

Storing debug log for failure in /home/nyros/.pip/pip.log
```

I thinks the problem is with git urls in the requirements.txt . Please check the following requirements.txt and let me know what to modify to install requirements.

```
-e hg+https://bitbucket.org/descent/django-aloha@844a88f99fba4fd3e29771fe85d6c611e66cd2e5#egg=django_aloha-dev

-e git+https://github.com/Bouke/django-filebrowser-no-grappelli.git@a367570e795288281be303f7c2505803f7a48543#egg=django_filebrowser-origin/HEAD



-e git+https://github.com/toastdriven/django-haystack.git@4d90d7d6c77ebf7ee298f2de941b1f41d99caf1d#egg=django_haystack-master



-e git+https://github.com/jowolf/django-ide.git@a2aa7a8ae41298c4635ba6c8c3b634a130c653d9#egg=django_ide-master

-e git+https://github.com/bread-and-pepper/django-userena.git@5beff3929f261694f9af03f940e500586e2a60d3#egg=django_userena-origin/HEAD



-e git+https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk@a12457671d3cb6265c52d9e8ef1ea2b387299fe3#egg=facebook_sdk-master
```

Comment: Try replacing the https in the URL with git! Also check if those repositories still exist!

Comment: I tried ,it no use , @MudassirRazvi

Comment: those repositories exist, but the @ commits not.

Comment: -e git+https://github.com/Bouke/django-filebrowser-no-grappelli.git@a367570e795288281be303f7c2505803f7a48543#egg=django_filebrowser-origin/HEAD


Try removing /HEAD from the url

Comment: I think @serakiel is correct. To be specific, remove `/HEAD` from the end of each URL, where the `#egg=` portion is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The form for importing specific commits from github does not require https, nor does it require the /HEAD at the end of your imports. See the following import for a development branch of django:

```
-e git://github.com/django/django.git@8568e7cfa4fb87cd0a9ead1b3fbb7a39d19e98b9#egg=django
```

Remove those portions and see if that settles your problem.

Comment: Interested in if this helped you solve your problem. Feel free to give it the ol' check mark if it did.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my issue is with /HEAD at the end of git url.

Comment: Yes. And in my answer, "nor does it require the /HEAD at the end of your imports." Was this not what you needed?

Comment: yes, sorry @Pythagoras I missed that /head in your comment, I accepted your answer , Thank you.